# Different representations of 3d cartesian axes

Tags: geometry

I am reading a book about graphics and game development.  (***3D Math primer for graphics and game development***) and I'm trying to solve an exercise.

"3.List the 48 different possible ways that the 3D axes may be assigned to the directions“north,” “east,” and“ up.” Identify which of these combinations are left-handed, and which ones are right-handed."

Can someone explain to me the thought process that led to having 48 ways? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The $+x$ vector can be in any of the $6$ directions.  The $y$ vector can be in any of the $4$ directions perpendicular to the chosen $x$ direction.  The $z$ vector can be in one of $2$ directions perpendicular to the other two.

Multiply these.

Comment: ! thanks man. i was trying to solve it with combinations and got the number of 24 which is the number of rotations for either right handed or left handed rotations. but i didnt know how what would 4x3x2x1 actually represented. but your way is much better.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the answer in the book was as follows, my other question is:

Is there way to do it methodically according to a certain rule, or do i have to do it manually per case in my head ?

```
          Left-handed                      Right-handed
```

East, Up, North, East, Up, North ......East, Up, North, East, Up, North

```
+x  +y  +z     −x   −y   +z      −x   −y   −z    +x   +y    −z

+x  −y  −z     −x   +y   −z      −x   +y   +z    +x   −y    +z

+x  +z  −y     −x   −z   −y      −x   −z   +y    +x   +z    +y

+x  −z  +y     −x   +z   +y      −x   +z   −y    +x   −z    −y

+y  +z  +x     −y   −z   +x      −y   −z   −x    +y   +z    −x

+y  −z  −x     −y   +z   −x      −y   +z   +x    +y   −z    +x

+y  +x  −z     −y   −x   −z      −y   −x   +z    +y   +x    +z

+y  −x  +z     −y   +x   +z      −y   +x   −z    +y   −x    −z

+z  +x  +y     −z   −x   +y      −z   −x   −y    +z   +x    −y

+z  −x  −y     −z   +x   −y      −z   +x   +y    +z   −x    +y

+z  +y  −x     −z   −y   −x      −z   −y   +x    +z   +y    +x

+z  −y  +x     −z   +y   +x      −z   +y   −x    +z   −y    −x
```